# Howto migrate config.persistence.classes subclasses

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-10.x

As descibed in [Breaking: #87623](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html), the `config.persistence.classes` typoscript configuration is replaced with the the `EXT:extension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` file.

This is my old typoscript configuration:

```
plugin.tx_news {
  persistence {
    classes {

      GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News {
        subclasses {
          0 = Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\News
        }
      }

      Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\News {
        mapping {
          recordType = 0
          tableName = tx_news_domain_model_news
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

This is my new `/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` file so far:

```
return [

    \Vendor\News\Domain\Model\News::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'recordType' => 0,
    ],

];
```

How do I configure the missing part with the subclasses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done the same way, see: https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/8857b7cf0e174047fd06d8f22dd28eef5c43503a/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php

```php
return [
    \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News::class => [
        'subclasses' => [
            \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\News::class
        ]
    ]
]
```